# MSSQL: Pre-run query affects rebuilding index?

Tags: sql-server

Can someone explain please what happens in the following situation:

A database was restored from backup. Then I rebuilt one index (which is fast 99% fragmented) and executed a query. It took about 2min. When I had rebuilt this index again, it took only 2s.

So if I don't rebuild the index again, my query works really slow. The statistics and execution plans are in both case identical (that's after first and second index rebuilding).

Comment: `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` in the middle of _fast_ scenario.

Comment: We can't repro the issue,moreover how are you saying the slowness is due to fragmentation,are you sure the first time,you don't have lockings ,blockings ?

Comment: DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS doesn't help

Comment: Yes, I don't have lockings..

Comment: If you restore backup, then run your query and after that run your query again without rebuilding index - what are the timings of both calls?

Comment: They are almost the same - again about 2min. But if I rebuild the index after running the query two times and then run it the third time, it works very fast